# 2017 Hyundai Elantra 2.0L #2 cylinder misfire

Tags: hyundai, elantra, cylinder

I borrowed my dads OBD2 tool (BlueDriver) did a scan, the codes returned were for that specific cylinder misfiring. Purchased an ignition coil (as that has been the issue on previous 4 cars with that code - different vehicles) installed it, went to clear codes...

The BlueDriver app took like 20mins to complete, didn’t clear the code. Car feels like it runs better but the dang code is on still. I’m curious to whether the driver for that model is maybe buggy and didn’t clear the code but the issue is resolved.

Is there a way I can forcefully clear codes, temporarily? In my Jeep I can totally clear codes even if the issue remains, it won’t code for about 30km.

I’m tempted to swap the plug next and see if that does it. Should have started with that but I digress.

What else could it be with cylinder misfire?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Two diagnostic things you can do. First, change the coil with a different coil and see if the code follows the coil. Second, to get it to clear the codes (at least at first) is to disconnect the battery for 20 mins. While the battery is disconnected, you can help the process by pressing on the brake pedal for 20 seconds or so (drains residual power in the system).

Comment: Another way to help the reset @Paulster2 is to disconnect the battery and then touch the cables together. Also, not all code readers are equal - some are better at some cars than others, so try a different code reader/scanner.

Comment: I made many mistakes. I should have swapped the plugs and coils first and see if the issue changed cylinders. 100%. Unfortunately I did this at end of day, outside and it’s cold here. So I opted out of troubleshooting and just bought a new coil.

Comment: I was told by a buddy that disconnecting the battery can actually cause adverse issues. His Jetta prompted him for a code to tenable the anti theft when he swapped battery. So I’m reluctant to try that, thoughts?